# Python-VTK: Offload computations to GPU

Tags: python, gpu, vtk

I've written a bunch of Python scripts that rely on VTK and run these on my Mac. I found that Activity Monitor lists that these scripts **do not** require High Performance GPU even though my machine has one (NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB). Paraview (based on VTK), though, is listed as requiring High Performance GPU.

**Question:** How do I get my Python scripts to benefit from High Performance GPU? Is there anything I should set in the script?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there were `OpenGL` alternatives to some common VTK pipeline activities:

1. `vtk.vtkOpenGLRenderer()` instead of `vtk.vtkRenderer()`
2. `vtk.vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper()` instead of `vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()`
3. `vtk.vtkOpenGLActor()` instead of `vtk.vtkActor()`

There are also many other classes such as `vtkOpenGLCamera()` and so on, which can be viewed on the docs ([VTK classes](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/7.0/html/classes.html)).